# Host a website on your virtual pc and access it on the internet

Tags: virtualhost, web-hosting

My friend and I are talking about hosting a website that is in development, We have a single computer(windows7) and would like to host a website virtually on this computer.

**Scenario is:**

**Main Windows(windows7)** - Will be used regularly and normally for coding, browsing, editing stuff. 
**Virtual Windows(No idea)** - Will be used only for the "hosting" using **WAMP**.

The hosted virtual server would be accessible over the internet or publicly not just on LAN and this settings would run automatically on every boot of the computer. Not really concern about the hosting being up or down since it's just a test server.

Tried searching and all the search results came back with a "**private or LAN**" only settings. Any ideas on this guys?

Comment: 1. This doesn't appear to be related to systems administration on a professional level. 2. This is very basic stuff and is not a good fit here. Try Googling the term "port forwarding" to get some ideas as to what you need to do.

Comment: Okay, It's nice to know that the idea is "port forwarding". Now if you don't mind sir, Now that you're here. Would you at least guide us up or at least put on some detailed guides(link) that you know. I'm pretty sure this would be pretty helpful too on the others like me.

Answer (score 1):

Basic rundown:

Easiest way would be to set your virtualization software so that your virtual machine networking is using bridged mode. That will give it its own IP address.

Now go to your router, poke around in the settings for anything related to NAT or port forwarding. Tell it to forward port 80 from the internet (source) to the IP address of the virtual machine (destination).

You'll probably have to open port 80 on the virtual Windows firewall too.

You may or may not have to edit something within WAMP to allow external access to the WAMP server; it's been a while since I had to use it so I don't remember.

Now anybody on the internet can access your web site via your public IP address (whatismyip.com).

Comment: We are currently trying things up. Anyway, will ask for specific questions in the near future if problems came-up. We kinda need a detailed steps on the **WAMP** server.

Comment: This is not the correct site to be asking these questions. If you're not sure why, read through the pages under the "help" link at the top of the page.